# iOS - Capturing button click on subview added to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I am trying to use the [`CollapseClick`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/collapseclick) table control. This all works, but I can't seem to add a button event to the view that is shown when the table cell is expanded.

Looking through the code, it is `UITableView`, which created `UITableViewCell`s and adds `UIView`s dynamically.  I think the `UIView` is added here:

```
+ (CollapseClickCell *)newCollapseClickCellWithTitle:(NSString *)title index:(int)index    content:(UIView *)content {
    NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollapseClickCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    CollapseClickCell *cell = [[CollapseClickCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCCHeaderHeight)];
    cell = [views objectAtIndex:0];

    // Initialization Here
    cell.TitleLabel.text = title;
    cell.index = index;
    cell.TitleButton.tag = index;
    cell.ContentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.ContentView.frame.origin.x, cell.ContentView.frame.origin.y, cell.ContentView.frame.size.width,  content.frame.size.height);
    [cell.ContentView addSubview:content];

    return cell;
}
```

The button displays, but if I try and hook up any events I cannot capture them.

It's probably quite simple.  I have put the app here: http://www.havoc-media.com/TravelApp.zip

Comment: Tom, I have found a resolution to your issue/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon looking at your code, you have a few overlooks, when it comes to using views.

The most important thing to know about views are that in order to have click events register on subviews the parent view cannot be smaller. The silly thing here is that even though you can visually see a view you inject into your ContentView, the Content view's width is set to zero, which means that all the views inside the ContentView may show, but will not respond to click events and the click events will default to the parentview of the ContentView, thus making your buttons unusable and unresponsive.

To address this in your openCollapseClickCellAtIndex you need to add the code:

```
cell.ContentView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.ContentView.frame.origin.x, cell.ContentView.frame.origin.y, 320, cell.ContentView.frame.size.height);
```

Your second issue is your CollapseClickCell xib you created is not communicating back to the view controller. Which means the view you created in the view controller and injected in the CollapseClickCell xib of which you want to report back to the view controller....isn't.

There is a way to address this but in my opinion I would create another custom xib-A to inject into your CollapseClickCell, and have the xib-A handle your button click events instead of test1View. Create a xib called "testView" linked to a test class and put this code in

```
-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index
 {
  NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"testView" owner:nil options:nil];

  UIView *content = [views objectAtIndex:0];

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return content; /*test1View;*/
      break;
```

Once these two issues are addressed, your code will work. I can include the additions I made to your code to make it work if you would like to see it?

Comment: Thanks Benny - this had me flummoxed for yonks. How did you find out about the UIView size issue? Intrigued.. Presume for "custom xib-A to inject" I would be replacing UIViews with xib's - connected to their own view controllers?

Comment: Presume for "custom xib-A to inject" I would be replacing UIViews with xib's - connected to their own view controllers? --> Yes, or their own class, just like, you have with the ContentCell xib. Glad I could help, project looks good!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code is not correct:

```
NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollapseClickCell" owner:nil options:nil];
CollapseClickCell *cell = [[CollapseClickCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCCHeaderHeight)];
cell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
```

You are first creating a cell via `[collapseClickCell alloc]`. But after that you assign the first object of the array created with `loadNibNamed:owner:options:nil` to the same variable. You either load the cell from the nib or you create it programatically. Simply put, you should just use:

```
NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CollapseClickCell" owner:nil options:nil];
CollapseClickCell *cell = [views objectAtIndex:0];
```

Be aware that the rect you were providing to the `initWithFrame:` method was not being used at all

Adding buttons to a cell is not the most appropriate thing (the whole cell should be the button). But if you absolutely need to, try assigning a uibutton as the accessory view of the cell. Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView

Something similar to:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (obtain your cell)
UIButton *button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Comment: While correct this still doesn't address the issue of the button not responding.

Comment: It should; if the accessory view of a cell is a UIControl it should respond to taps. It's like using the default disclosure indicator (blue round arrow)

Comment: You need to look at the code and try your response, the content cell is still 0 in width which in turns it won't respond to touch events.

Not saying what you stated is wrong, it needed to be addressed, it just doesn't address the issue